# python: list manipulation

Tags: python, list

I have a list `L` of objects (for what it's worth this is in scons). I would like to create two lists `L1` and `L2` where `L1` is `L` with an item `I1` appended, and `L2` is `L` with an item `I2` appended.

I would use `append` but that modifies the original list.

How can I do this in Python? (sorry for the beginner question, I don't use the language much, just for scons)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
L1 = L + [i1]
L2 = L + [i2]
```

That is probably the simplest way. Another option is to copy the list and then append:

```
L1 = L[:]       #make a copy of L
L1.append(i1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
L1=list(L)
```

duplicates the list. I guess you can figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of your list

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y.append(4)
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> z = list(x)
>>> z.append(5)
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

or use concatenation, which will make a new list

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x + [4]
>>> z = x + [5]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

The former is probably a touch more idiomatic/common, but the latter works fine in this case. Some people also copy using slicing (`x[:]` makes a new list with all the elements of the original list `x` referred to) or the `copy` module. Neither of these are awful, but I find the former a touch cryptic and the latter a bit silly.